# NA message in converting list to numeric

Tags: r

i want to convert factor data to numeric vector and i used

```
 as.numeric.factor(data$a)
```

but it returns NA  with Warning message:

```
 In as.numeric.factor(data$mande) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

`data$mande` is as below:

```
 [1]  487,133,554        935,324,956        911,218,601        852,769,205     827,303,376       822,798,080   
 [7]  790,742,637        705,988,860      708,069,041      822,576,228      1,030,917,702   993,681,929   
[13]  612,788,943     476,228,323     698,824,239     742,635,939     1,015,681,208   560,344,408   
[19]  534,239,403     593,466,633     845,546,563     945,040,231     662,027,082     939,183,094   
[25]  567,896,868     895,193,731     596,684,741     816,154,728     584,770,698     888,124,557   
[31]  714,095,214     926,332,917     1,048,748,054   859,163,643     779,785,761     769,739,089   
[37]  637,955,119     1,013,591,480   847,255,948     401,628,954     753,706,919     610,029,520   
[43]  643,316,067     864,681,638     1,030,589,838   772,686,642     915,548,834     839,074,449   
[49]  944,666,653     577,565,091     507,186,304     493,750,994     533,159,975     777,006,295   
[55]  740,415,930     937,675,395     957,068,513     811,641,347     911,885,721     937,100,021   
[61]  931,185,060     576,935,553   
62 Levels:  1,013,591,480   1,015,681,208   1,030,589,838   1,030,917,702   1,048,748,054  ...  993,681,929
```

what should i do to have numeric vector data?

Comment: Please show `data$mande`.

Comment: I am using this one ``as.numeric(as.character(data$a))``

Comment: @ghazal You can edit your question (I have done so for you now). Please don't post clarifications as answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the format of your data. Use this:

```
as.numeric(gsub(",","",as.character(data$mande)))
```

`gsub` removes the commas and enables R to transform the data to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

try

`as.numeric(as.character(data$mande))`